# To display original html page without default page(Spring security)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I m studying spring security.

I want to display original html file(loginForm) in spring security when I click localhost/8080:loginForm.

but it shows default page of spring security.
it says please sign in(which i didnt make)

How can I modify it?

build gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    // springsecurityを依存関係に追加
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    // thymeleaf拡張ライブラリを依存関係に追加
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/loginForm").permitAll() 
                .anyRequest().authenticated(); // 
        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login") 
                .loginPage("/loginForm") 
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password") 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true) 
                .failureUrl("/loginForm?error");
```

LoginController.java

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/loginForm")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "loginForm";
    }
}
```

loginForm.html(what I want to display)

```html
<body>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        <p>ユーザ名またはパスワードが違います。</p>
    </div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>メールアドレス: </label>
             <input type="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>パスワード: </label>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="ログイン">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```